iterate through accounts in AWS to create inventory source
Here is the environment:

list of multiple accounts in AWS (in reality, these are all digits):
account1
account2
account3

one id that has assumed role capability across all accounts

successfully generated list of assumed roles (including arn, session_token, session_name)

Ansible Automation Platform (AAP aka Tower)

inventory exists "dyn_aws_inventory"


Goal:
iterate through all the assumed roles
create an inventory source for each with name '<role_session_name>_src'
all servers in account show up under 'dyn_aws_inventory/Hosts'
able to refresh each inventory source
Attempted:
    - name: Create an AWS EC2 inventory source
      ansible.controller.inventory_source:
        controller_oauthtoken: "{{ controller_oauthtoken }}"
        name: "{{ vpc_session.invocation.module_args.role_session_name }}_src"
        source: "ec2"
'#      credential: ### this worked for a single account, not the list
        inventory: "{{ inv_out.id }}"
        overwrite: true
        overwrite_vars: true
        source_vars:
          plugin: amazon.aws.aws_ec2
          session_token: "{{ vpc_session.sts_creds.session_token  }}" # <== tried with and without
          assume_role_arn: "{{ vpc_session.invocation.module_args.role_arn }}_src" <== tried with and without
          regions:
          - us-east-1
          - us-east-2
          filters:
            instance-state-name: running
          compose:
            ansible_hostname:
            - "tag:Name"
      ignore_errors: true
      loop: "{{ aws_assumed_roles.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ vpc_session.invocation.module_args.role_session_name }}"
        loop_var: vpc_session
      register: inv_source_out

Actual results:
inventory sources created within correct inventory, but no servers are imported
any inventory source refresh fails with this error:
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /runner/inventory/aws_ec2.yml with auto plugin:
An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the AssumeRole operation:
The security token included in the request is invalid.

I don't have the answer, post only to say I have a very similar problem.
In my scenario, I have an ID that has rights to assume role on another AWS account. I can perform the assume role on the AWS account via the CLI with no issue. I have our AAP Controller (aka Tower) configured with only the AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key Credential of the account that has rights to assume roles (I didnt enter a STS Token as I dont have one at this point). I then configure the Dynamic Inventory plugin for the account I want to assume roles on by setting the source variable "iam_role_arn" to the ARN of the account. I also provide the region. However, when I run a sync, I get the same error as you.
What does work for me (but in my opinion defeats the purpose of automation), is assuming the role via a CLI, and inputting the Access Key ID, Secret Access Key, and Session Token generated by the assume command into the AWS Credential in AAP. Then removing the "iam_role_arn" from the source variable. Sync worked. The reason I don't like this, is I would have to manually generate the credentials every time, which would defeat the purpose if you were trying to run an event driven automation.
I am hoping someone knows a solution or knows if perhaps there is something wrong with the community plugin.
[Update 15Apr2024] Further testing I have found with the AWS Dynamic Inventory plugin, when using the "regions" variable it fails, even when specifying a single region. However, if I use just "region" variable, everything works as expected. I will be submitting a ticket to the vendor that I believe this to be a bug.

Here is the scenario that eventually worked.  The code sample below is limited to this specific solution.  Feel free to comment with questions if you want more context.
TL/DR: In the main playbook, use a separate entity like task or role, to get the session token and do the action.  The token expires as soon as there is a new user context.
Here is the playbook that does the following:

get a list of account ids
find the id of an existing inventory
call a role named 'create_inventory_sources_aws'


    ---
    - name: Create an AWS EC2 inventory source in AAP
      hosts: localhost
      connection: local
      gather_facts: true
      collections:
        - ansible.controller
    
    
      vars:
        inventory_name: "sample_inventory_name"
        org_name: "sample_org_name"
        aws_accounts:
          - 000000000001
          - 000000000002
          - 000000000003
    
    
      tasks:
        - name: Find the inventory ID
          ansible.controller.inventory:
            name: "{{ inventory_name }}"
            organization: "{{ org_name }}"
          register: inv_out
            - inv_search_only
    
    
        - name: get assume_role and inventory for each account id
          ansible.builtin.include_role:
            name: ../roles/create_inventory_sources_aws
          loop: "{{ aws_accounts }}"
          loop_control:
            loop_var: aws_account_id


Here is the content of the role 'create_inventory_sources_aws' in the 'roles' folder of the working directory of the current playbook:

    ---
      - name: try assume role
        amazon.aws.sts_assume_role:
          access_key: <your_AWS_access_key>
          secret_key: <your_AWS_secret_key>
          role_arn: "arn:aws:iam::{{ aws_account_id }}:role/existing_role_in_all_accounts"
          role_session_name: "AnsibleSession-{{ aws_account_id }}"
          validate_certs: false
        register: aws_assumed_role
        ignore_errors: true
    
      - name: logit assumed role info (mostly to see keys and session token)
        ansible.builtin.debug:
          var: aws_assumed_role
    
      - name: set re-used vars
        ansible.builtin.set_fact:
          currentInvSrc: "{{ aws_assumed_role.sts_user.assumed_role_id }}_src"
    
      - name: "Create an AWS EC2 inventory source for account {{ aws_account_id }}"
        ansible.controller.inventory_source:
          controller_oauthtoken: "{{ controller_oauthtoken }}"
          name: "{{ currentInvSrc }}"
          source: "ec2"
          inventory: "{{ inv_out.id }}"
          overwrite: true
          overwrite_vars: true
          source_vars:
            plugin: amazon.aws.aws_ec2
            access_key: "{{ aws_assumed_role.sts_creds.access_key }}"
            secret_key: "{{ aws_assumed_role.sts_creds.secret_key }}"
            session_token: "{{ aws_assumed_role.sts_creds.session_token  }}"
            regions:
            - us-east-1
            - us-east-2
            hostnames:
              - "tag:Name"
              - name: 'private-ip-address'
        ignore_errors: true
        register: inv_source_out
    
    
      - name: "Update inventory source {{ currentInvSrc }}"
        ansible.controller.inventory_source_update:
          controller_oauthtoken: "{{ controller_oauthtoken }}"
          name: "{{ currentInvSrc }}"
          inventory: "{{ inv_out.id }}"
        register: inv_source_update_out


The result should be an existing inventory called 'sample_inventory_name', populated with 3 sources:

<unique_id>:AnsibleSession-000000000001_src
<unique_id>:AnsibleSession-000000000002_src
<unique_id>:AnsibleSession-000000000003_src

and should contain all the servers from each account, from every region you entered in the 'regions:' sections above.
